# Multiple Accounts Policy

Tags: discussion, user-accounts

What is the policy on multiple accounts, especially maintenance accounts?. On Wikiepedia, a [maintenance account is acceptable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Sock_puppetry#Legitimate_uses) as long as the maintenance account links back to the user's main account.

This question is prompted by the new user [Retag](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/users/5513/retag), which is going good work, albeit anonymously.

Comment: btw, we use the `policy` tag for policy questions. See the post tagged `meta-policy` for more information.

Answer (score 5):

I have created the user Retag, you can see my name there, but I will add a link to my user page.

I have created it since it doesn't feel good when my name is all over the front page just because of retagging question while I haven't added any new information to those questions.

We have filed a feature request to SE that ratagging should not bump the questions to the top or at least the name of the last user performing a *significant* edit should be displayed on the active questions page but they haven't been accepted.

I think we should at least get an interesting questions page like the one on SO on cstheory (if we have to leave with properties of SE system that we don't like because users on SO and other SE site like them (to keep the system uniform), then we should also get this useful feature on cstheory too).

About multiple accounts, we haven't had a policy on cstheory AFAIK, don't know about the general SE rules.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply and linking to your main account. I agree with the feature request for bumps only with significant edits.

Comment: I think having [the interesting questions page](http://stackoverflow.com/?tab=interesting) will be a considerable improvement, but it seems that they are [still](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/06/se-podcast-07/) a little bit unhappy about our response to [their proposal](http://meta.cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/947/is-theoretical-computer-science-too-narrow).

Comment: How does a question become regarded as interesting?

Comment: @Tyson, it is explained [here](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/stack-overflow-homepage-changes/).

Comment: @Kaveh: Can we somehow flag questions for Retag?

Comment: @Kaveh: Ping..?

Comment: @Jukka: sorry, I didn't got the first @ alert. I don't think that would work. Btw, logging in with two different accounts is time consuming so I am not doing it regularly, I may go over the recent questions and retag them next week if I find time.